# Update parameter value in switch block according to the value of a constant block during simulation in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Here is what I'm trying to do

Here is the model:

[image: model]

I want to change the Threshold parameter value in the simulation to be a function of the value of the constant block. (i.e. 0.4 * value of the constant block value)

This is the parameter I want to change during simulation:

[image: parameter]

I can easily change the value of the constant block during simulation but I want the threshold value of the switch block to change simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an additional Relational Operator block.

[image: model]

So there is a test, for `threshold_signal > 0.4*1`, which passes either a 0 or 1. Then trigger your switch based on if that signal is greater than 0.5 to split the two cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a way to dynamically change the threshold value without adding additional blocks (i.e. the constant value = sp, the threshold value = 0.4 * sp and I can change sp so the threshold value will change)

Comment: If, say, `sp = 100`, you can just put `0.4*100` in the input box of the switch block and Simulink will evaluate that to `40`. If you are running your variables from a Matlab script then you can have a workspace variable `sp = 100` and type `0.4*sp` into the block parameter box. Does that help?